# How can I use the function"warpAffine" to warpAffine any Mat I want to deal with? not only the (uchar)img?

Tags: opencv

When I use the function "warpAffine" to deal with CV_32S Mat or some others, it will be error. I found that: Maybe, the "warpAffine" can only deal with  mat, am I right?
If not, how can I warpAffine other type Mats?  Thanks you!

Here, if src is not uchar type, it will be error.

```
Mat src= Mat::zeros( 50, 50, CV_32S  );
Mat warp_dst= Mat::zeros( src.rows, (int)src.cols*1.41421356+1,  CV_32S  );
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)   
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            (int)src.at<int>(i,j) =i*j;
            cout << (int)src.at<int>(i,j) <<endl;
        }
    srcTri[0] = Point2f( 0.0,0.0 );
    srcTri[1] = Point2f( src.cols*1.0 - 1, 0 );
    srcTri[2] = Point2f( 0, src.rows*1.0 - 1 );
    dstTri[0] = Point2f( src.cols*0.0, src.rows*0.0 );
    dstTri[1] = Point2f( src.cols*1.0-1, src.rows*0.0 );
    dstTri[2] = Point2f( src.cols*0.41421356-1, src.rows*1.0-1 );
warp_mat = getAffineTransform( srcTri, dstTri );
warpAffine( src, warp_dst, warp_mat, warp_dst.size() );
```

Comment: where is img2? warpAffine requires the Mat of output array is of the same type of the input. Try converting the input to CV_32S and see if you can get CV_32S output.

Comment: Thank you ,james. img2 is src, I have corrected it. My input and output is all CV_32S, and I follow the debug, it will stop after some cycles in the function" void cv::warpAffine".